# Flask Template Not found

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Implementing a simple static site from flask, but the browser says template not found, the shell returned 404

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

TemplateNotFound: template.html
```

The main python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def template_test():
    return render_template('template.html', my_string="Wheeeee!", my_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have the following file structure:

```
flask_new_practice
|--template/
    |--template.html
|--run.py
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

By default, Flask looks in the `templates` folder in the root level of your app.

> http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/
>
> template_folder – the folder that contains the templates that should
>   be used by the application. Defaults to 'templates' folder in the root
>   path of the application.

So you have some options,

1. rename `template` to `templates`
2. supply a `template_folder` param to have your `template` folder recognised by the flask app:

   ```
   app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
   ```

Comment: app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates'),  => `templetes`