# Making a template with Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask

Trying to run a static html with FLask. I keep getting the error: TemplateNotFound: lucky.html

Ive examined another post similar at: [Flask Template Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396064/flask-template-not-found) however it did not help my problem. I have tried to move the templates directory around containing the lucky.html file with no luck

File path:

```
C:\Python27\flask_practice\templates
lucky.html
lucky.py
```

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def lucky():
    return render_template('lucky.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Html:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <p> Hello there </p>
        <p> Feeling lucky </p>
        <p> 7 </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your directories are not set up correctly.

In my flask app, i'm using the following (`project_folder/__init__.py`):

```
app = Flask(__name__)

my_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([
    app.jinja_loader,
    jinja2.FileSystemLoader(app.config["TEMPLATEDIR"]),
])
app.jinja_loader = my_loader
```

with `TEMPLATEDIR = "templates"`.

My project looks like:

```
root
    project_folder/__init__.py
    templates/404.html
```

Comment: had to do something different but it was because my directories were not setup correctly. thanks