# Rendering html template with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, html-templates

im trying to render html template that i download free from a website.
every time i run the program it just result error 404 Not Found

[Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.]

and in the vscode it give me

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2023 14:12:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

result.

```
my path//

-project
  -templates
    -index.html
  -main.py
```

this my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

is everyone have a though what should i do so i can run the html template with no errors?
thank you for who can answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How are you accessing this flask app?

Comment: Rename `template` folder to `templates`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask Template Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396064/flask-template-not-found)

Comment: acces flalsk from python, @ewokx its already name templates, nope atshaik

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the Flask app.

```
import os

base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))    
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=f'{base_dir}\\project\\templates\\')
```

and also make the app.route a decorator:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```