# "Error with Python Flask route not rendering template - 'TemplateNotFound'

Tags: python, flask

`**Background:**
I'm working on a web application using Python Flask to render templates. I have a route defined in my Flask app that is supposed to render a template, but I'm encountering an issue.

**Objective:**
I want to render the 'index.html' template when accessing the '/home' route.

**Code Snippet:**
Here's the relevant part of my Flask app:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I'm getting the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Comment: you are "*using Python Flask*", but how is that related to Java, why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask Template Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396064/flask-template-not-found)

Comment: Does your index.html exist in a folder named "templates"? Because this is the place where flask will look for the template